# Port unreachable after deploying NGINX image to IBM Bluemix Container Cloud

Tags: nginx, docker, ibm-cloud

I'm doing the following:

```
docker pull ngnix
docker tag 6886fb5a9b8d registry.ng.bluemix.net/rkie/nginx 
docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/rkie/nginx
```

Then using the Bluemix Web UI I create a new container (Medium, 2 GB, 128 GB HD, assign an IP and put `80`, `443` into the port list and click create.

Unfortunately nothing is available on this IP/Port.

Comment: can you provide more sample code? I've never done this, but I would like to test it on my end and see if i can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Here a few hints on how to check your configuration is alright:

1. Make sure you have assigned a public Ip address
   Use: *ice ip list*, *ice ip bind*
2. Make sure your port is actually mapped to the container

   - Use: *ice inspect CONTAINER* to view the detailed configuration of your container

Comment: "PortBindings": {
            "80/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostPort": "80"
                }
            ]
        }, but thanks a lot!

Comment: Same thing here. Does it say "PortMapping": null under "NetworkSettings" too?

Answer (score 0):

This is a temporary defect as can be seen here:

https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/207369/port-unreachable-after-deploying-nginx-image-to-ib.html#answer-207459